# Can I create Report without using crystal report in Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have been working on reporting last 2 years, but till i am using crystal report and .rdlc reports, I want to know that "is it possible to create report with out using Crystal Reports or RDLC Reports"?, if it is possible so please tell me, how to do it.

Currently I am working on visual studio 2013 and SQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: did you take a look at SSRS? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms159106.aspx

Comment: Hey Mate thank for Rply,I tried to use SSRS but, i want to create customize report (ie; Invoices) and i don't know how to use it.

Comment: You can create reports using the many 3rd party reporting tools in the market or even create your own. Each product requires that you learn it using the material the company publishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQL Server Reporting Services. Check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms159106.aspx)

Comment: Finally find few options SSRS or just save text into .txt file.